# Good Patterns to pass down data in deep OOP composition?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

This is a general open question about best practices and scalability in Python using OOP.

Overtime, I have been using in several projects Class inheritance and composition. This pattern has helped me abstracting and encapsulating a lot of the code. However, as the codebase increases, I have been trapped in a recurrent pattern where I have a "master" Class which "orchestrates" another classes by composition, which in turn also have another composed classes to orchestrate and so on. This creates a "deep" tree structure of dependant classes.

The problem is that if I want to pass down arguments to many of the Class components from the master class, I have to pass it down on everytime I init the class again and again, writing redundant code. For example (a simple example just to illustrate the kindof composition but imagine a much deeper structure than this):

```
 class UploaderExecutor:
     def __init__(self, mediatype: Literal['video', 'image'], channel: Literal['online', 'offline'], ...):
     self.uploader = Uploader(mediatype, channel, ...)
     self.validator = Validator(mediatype, channel, ...)
     self.reporter = Reporter(mediatype, ...)
     ...

 class Uploader():
     def __init__(self, mediatype, channel, ...):
         self.configurator = Configurator(mediatype, channel...)
         self.file_parser = FileParser(mediatype, channel...)
         self.Notificator = Notificator(mediaype, channel...)
         ...

 class Validator():
     def __init__(self, mediatype, channel, ...):
         self.file_validator = FileValidator(mediatype, channel...)
         self.name_validator = NameValidator(channel...)
         ...

 class Reporter():
     def __init__(self, mediatype, channel, ...):
         self.slack_reporter = SlackReporter(mediatype, channel...)
         self.telegram_reporter = TelegramReporter(mediatype, channel...)
         ...

   #etc etc
```

I guess this pattern of passing down arguments to all the composed classes is not escalable as more and more cases are added. Also I do not want to rely in solutions like global variables, because I want to decide which data passing down to which composed classes (maybe not all of them would need for example `mediatype`). So my question is which kind of abstractions or design patterns are recommended in these cases?

Comment: Rather than passing the raw mediatype, channel, etc. and then constructing the FileValidator, TelegramReporter, etc. in the `__init__`, try create the FileValidator, etc. before hand and instead pass them into the `__init__`. I think this might tidy things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that following the O.O.P. principles, you can design this example starting from a class - let's say `MediaFile`. This can (ideally) encapsulate and completely hide the `mediatype` and `channel` literals and only expose methods such as `upload()`, `validate()` and `report()`.

For different types of `MediaFile` objects, you can use polymorphism and implement these methods differently. If you have many combinations of, let's say mediatype + channel for creating the appropriate  MediaFile object, you can maybe use the factory pattern.

As a result, when adding a new type, you'll have to implement various methods for it and not touch code that is used by the other existing implementations. O.O.P. can help you decouple the code in this way.